# TinyMCE - Change focus after TinyMCE is loaded in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, focus, tinymce, anchor, onload

I found very strange problem in Chrome when using # in URL. If # doesn't exist - it's Ok, but when I set #something - page is loaded, tinyMCE is still loading (focus is on the top) and after complete and textarea changed to rich text editor then focus is changed to the middle of page. DO you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve. where do you want the cursor to be after the page has loaded?

Comment: I'd like always cursor and focus to be at the top of page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(){
    document.location.href = "#"; 
};
```

**Another try:** Put this in your tinymce init function

```
  setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
        document.location.href = "#"; 
    });
  },
```

Comment: Yes, try with this trick before and doesn't work. I set # in url in preview page where make request to page and include #